# Octave select a file?

Tags: file, openfiledialog, octave

Does Octave have a good way to let the user select an input file? I've seen code like this for Matlab, but doesn't work in Octave.

A gui based method would be preferred, but some sort of command-line choice would work also. It would be great if there were some way to do this that would work in both Matlab and Octave.

I found [this](http://octave.sourceforge.net/java/function/listdlg.m.html) for Matlab but it does not work in Octave, even when you install [Octave Forge](http://octave.sourceforge.net/functions_by_package.php) Java package for the listdlg function. In Octave, dir() gives you:

```
  647x1 struct array containing the fields:

    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
    statinfo
```

but I don't know how to convert this to an array of strings listdlg expects.

Comment: "good" as in a GUI-based method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already the [Octave Forge java package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/java/index.html) installed, so you can create instances of any java class and call any java method.

For example to create a `JFileChooser` and call the `JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(Component parent)` method:

```
frame = javaObject("javax.swing.JFrame");
frame.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
frame.setVisible(true);
fc = javaObject ("javax.swing.JFileChooser")
returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
file = fc.getSelectedFile();
file.getName()
```

Btw. I had some troubles installing the package.
Here is a [fix](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/java-package-breaks-with-Ubuntu-upgrade-to-10-04-td2256912.html) for Ubuntu. that worked also for my Debian Testing.

**EDIT**

@NoBugs In reply to your comment:

If you need to use listdlg you can do the following:

```
d = dir;
str = {d.name};
[sel,ok] = listdlg('PromptString','Select a file:',...
                'SelectionMode','single',...
                'ListString',str);
if ok == 1
    disp(str{sel(1)});
end
```

This should be compatible with matlab, by I cannot test it right now.

If you want to select multiple files use this:

```
d = dir;
str = {d.name};
[sel,ok] = listdlg('PromptString','Select a file:',...
                'SelectionMode','multiple',...
                'ListString',str);
if ok == 1
   imax = length(sel);
   for i=1:1:imax
      disp(str{sel(i)});
   end
end
```

Comment: Great code! It worked fine for me even without that fix, with Ubuntu and compiled Octave 3.4.2. However I was looking for code that would do the equivalent of the linked Matlab code, asking user to choose a file in current directory, using listdlg. Compatibility, or minimal differences from Matlab, would be a big plus.

Answer (score 0):

I never came across an open-file-dialog in octave.
If you are looking for a gui based method maybe [guioctave](http://guioctave.com/) can help you. I never used it, because it appears only be available for windows machines.

A possible solution would be to write a little script in octave, that would allow the user to parse through the directories and select a file like that.

Comment: Matlab can use Listdlg to prompt for a file: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/listdlg.html, and Octave has Listdlg also, if you install the Octaveforge Java package. However, I haven't been able to get it to prompt for a file using Matlab example code.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd provide an updated answer to this old question, since it is appearing in the 'related questions' field for other questions.

Octave provides the `uigetdir` and `uigetfile` functions, which do what you expect.